# Cloud Foundry Development Workflow

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm trying to figure out how to use Micro CloudFoundry for development as described when I read things like the following from the [Cloud Foundry blog](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/11/08/new-release-of-micro-cloud-foundry/):

"Rather than installing a web server (Tomcat, etc.), runtimes (Java, Ruby, etc.), and services (Postgres, MongoDB, etc.), you can do a single download of Micro Cloud Foundry, boot it up, and deploy your applications using ‘vmc push’."

When I'm developing (Node, Grails or Java web apps), I'm used to just refreshing and seeing my changes (well, always for client-side code, sometimes for server-side); it makes for very rapid and efficient development.

Constantly invoking 'vmc push' during development is pretty much a non-starter for me.  It's far too slow of a feedback cycle to be practical.  Is there a better way?  Does anyone actually do this?

What does your Cloud Foundry development workflow look like and where does Micro Cloud Foundry fit in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All issues with the delays involved in pushing an application to Cloud Foundry aside, I often use Micro Cloud Foundry for provisioning services (MySQL, MongoDB, Redis etc) and then use a local tunnel to connect to them via the vmc tunnel command.