# Efficient development flow for Cloud Foundry

Tags: docker, development-environment, cloud-foundry

The basic flow of making the change to the code and then pushing the code using IDE or CLI to the CF instance seems to be quite inefficient. What other approach exists, preferably with following characteristics:

- Ease of setting up the environment on a developer's machine including cases such as on boarding of new team member when the replicability and consistency is important
- Seamless development experience - change/deploy/test
- Support for local services binding and mocking/stubbing

There was similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485943/cloud-foundry-development-workflow) already but it is quite outdated and with the pace of changes in the industry (e.g. Docker explosion) there might be better alternatives to the push.

Comment: Why do you conclude that CF workflow is inefficient? I would think it delivers on a seamless development experience, considering a single "push" operation performs a build, archive and deploy in one step.

Comment: You can deploy your own Cloud Foundry locally (using virtualbox) or in a single-VM AWS instance: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/run-local.html. This is like running your own local Docker daemon or Docker-daemon-in-VM (if you're on OS X), except you get a full Cloud Foundry instead of only Docker.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor you are right, I should have formulate my question in a more neutral way. There is nothing wrong with "push" operation per se but I'm starting learning the CF way of doing things and was looking for some hints to do it right

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta thank you, I will try this approach